# How to set environment variables in Python and use them in a C extension

Tags: python

I have created a Python wrapper for a C library. The library requires an environment variable (`MY_DATA_FOLDER`) to point to a folder with some data files. The data files are (in the current implementation of my wrapper) installed together with the Python wrapper when running setup.py, and are placed in a folder called `coefficients` together with the package installation. I set the environment variables in the package's `__init__.py`, which is excecuted whenever the package is imported:

```
# set environment variable
import os
from os.path import join, realpath, dirname
MY_DATA_FOLDER = join(realpath(dirname(__file__)), 'coefficients')
os.environ['MY_DATA_FOLDER'] = MY_DATA_FOLDER

# import the C extension (mymodule._mymodule) after setting the variable above
from mymodule import _mymodule
```

The wrapper functions are now available as `mymodule._mymodule.myfunction()`. I am testing the package with tox, and everything works well. In case it's useful, my `testenv` has the following commands:

```
commands =
    python setup.py clean --all build_ext --force --inplace
    {posargs:py.test -vv --ignore=src}
```

However, when I install the package using `python setup.py install` (or `develop` or `pip install .` with or without `-e`) and open a Python shell to run the wrapper, the C library gives an error indicating that the environment variable is not set. This happens whether I run some custom code or run `py.test -vv --ignore=src` just like tox does. Everything is importable, and the C extension does run (i.e. it's compiled correctly), but the environment variable is not passed along, hence the error.

I have banged my head against the wall for some time now and I have no idea what could be wrong, and apparently neither does Google. Why is the environment variable available to the C extension when running tox but not when installing normally?

I'm happy to provide more information if it's required. The entire source is [here](https://github.com/cmeeren/aacgmv2).

---

### UPDATE

It works now. It seems to have been a classical case of "struggle for a few hours, give up and leave work, come back the next day, everything works." I have no idea why, but I must have done something wrong. Perhaps my environment wasn't as clean as I thought, or I forgot to activate it.

Comment: I've run `python setup.py install` from source, then tried in interpreter - `aacgmv2._aacgmv2.setDateTime` is accessible. Seems to work?

Comment: Try to install it into fresh virtualenv, maybe problem will go away.

Comment: It's accessible yes, but try to run the function, e.g. ``aacgmv2._aacgmv2.setDateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)``. That will fail (at least for me). I have tried a fresh environment (using conda), didn't work.

Comment: It returns None. Does it crash for you? I have Python 3.4 x86_64 on Linux Mint 17

Comment: It should return None. Happy to know it works. Then it's probably something on my end. I'll see if I can figure out what.

Comment: It seems to have been a classical case of "struggle for a few hours, give up and leave work, come back the next day, everything works." I have no idea why, but I must have done something wrong yesterday. Perhaps my environment wasn't as clean as I thought, or I forgot to activate it.

Comment: cmeeren, since this issue can no longer be reproduced, you should probably close the question.

Comment: Thanks, voted to close now.